# Como copiar todo un div que contiene texto y icono de font awesome al portapapeles utilizando navigator.clipboard

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código que me copia correctamente lo que se encuentra en las etiquetas `<p>` pero también quisiera que me copiara lo que contiene la propiedad `title` del icono que esta con `fontawesome` asociado a Red Social de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui comparto el codigo **HTML Y JAVASCRIPT**

```html
<!-- Agregar la librería Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Crear el elemento con el icono y su propiedad title -->
<div id="textCopy">
  <p>Nombre:</p>
  <p>Apellido:</p>
  <p>Red Social:</p>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter" title="Twitter"></i>
</div>
<br>
<!-- Agregar un botón para copiar la propiedad title del icono al portapapeles -->
<button onclick="copyTitleToClipboard()">Copiar título</button>

<script>
function copyTitleToClipboard() {
  var elementCopy = document.getElementById('textCopy').innerText; // obtener el valor de title del elemento
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(elementCopy).then(() => {
    console.log('Texto copiado al portapapeles.');
  }) 
  .catch(err =>{
    console.error('Error al copiar el texto al portapapeles.', err);
  });
}
</script>
```

El codigo funciona correctamente si lo corres en cualquier editor de codigo. Les agradezco su ayudo!!!

Esto es lo que me aparece:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero quisiera que con la propiedad `title` me pase el nombre de la red social.

Comment: Dices " también quisiera ...", como también???. Para copiar (de forma normal) se selecciona UN texto y se presiona ctrl+c, no se selecciona ni 2 o más texto. Entonces si tú quieres copiar 2 textos por código, debes unirlos en uno. Como lo quieres unir?, dicho de otra manera, cuando "pegues" cuál es tu resultado esperado?

Comment: Las etiquetas `<p>` las copia bien, pero me gustaria que cuando le de al boton copiar me permitiera copiar el `title` de la etiqueta `<i>` y se me mostrara como aparece en la imagen de arriba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega un `id` a la etiqueta `i` y obtienes el contenido de `title` con `document.getElementById('icon').title`, luego lo concatenas con la variable donde guardas lo demás asi:  `elementCopy += document.getElementById('icon').title;`, esto debería de dar salida: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código completo:

```
<!-- Agregar la librería Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Crear el elemento con el icono y su propiedad title -->
<div id="textCopy">
    <p>Nombre:</p>
    <p>Apellido:</p>
    <p>Red Social:</p>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter" title="Twitter" id="icon"></i>
</div>
<br>
<!-- Agregar un botón para copiar la propiedad title del icono al portapapeles -->
<button onclick="copyTitleToClipboard()">Copiar título</button>

<script>
    function copyTitleToClipboard() {
        var elementCopy = document.getElementById('textCopy').innerText; // obtener el valor de title del elemento
         elementCopy += document.getElementById('icon').title; // obtener el valor de title del elemento

        navigator.clipboard.writeText(elementCopy).then(() => {
            console.log('Texto copiado al portapapeles.', elementCopy);
        })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('Error al copiar el texto al portapapeles.', err);
            });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba. Saludos!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Puedes recorrer todos los elementos e ir preguntando si es del tipo `<i>` copiar el `tittle`, caso contrario copiar el `innerHTML`

```js
function copyTitleToClipboard() {
    let copyText = "";
    var elementCopy = document.getElementById('textCopy').querySelectorAll("*"); 
    elementCopy.forEach(e => {
        if (e.tagName == "I") {
            copyText += e.getAttribute("title") + ":\n";
        }
        else {
            copyText += e.innerHTML + "\n";
        }
  });
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText).then(() => {
    console.log('Texto copiado al portapapeles.');
  }) 
  .catch(err =>{
    console.error('Error al copiar el texto al portapapeles.', err);
  });
}
```

```html
<!-- Agregar la librería Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Crear el elemento con el icono y su propiedad title -->
<div id="textCopy">
  <p>Nombre:</p>
  <p>Apellido:</p>
  <p>Red Social:</p>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter" title="Twitter"></i>
</div>
<br>
<!-- Agregar un botón para copiar la propiedad title del icono al portapapeles -->
<button onclick="copyTitleToClipboard()">Copiar título</button>
```